# c - Trouble with scanf

Tags: c, scanf, delimiter

So I'm having some trouble formatting my scanf call to fit my input. Basically, I want to take an input of a string (maximum 32 characters) along with 2 integers (all separated by spaces). Currently, my code is:

```
scanf("%32s", str);
scanf("%*s %d %d", &first, &last);
```

I added the %*s in order to ignore any possible characters after the 32 I'm reading in. For some reason this %*s ignores the first number and reads the 2nd number from the input into &last. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want a certain number of characters to be discarded (4 in my answer) you can do this:

```
scanf("%*4s %d %d", &first, &last);
```

But the earlier one was discarding every character it saw and it didn't stop and consumed the digits of your int.

In this case, the thing I have shown will consume 4 characters and then read the `int`-s.

Example usage:

```
>54321 12
```

It will take in `first` and `last` `1` and `12` respectively. And check the return value of `scanf` here - which will be `2` in case the call succeeds. Extending the idea you will do this

```
scanf("%*32[^ \n] %d %d", &first, &last);
```

Here you will skip first 32 characters if they are not from the scanset `[^ \n]` and then rest of the things are inputted with `%d` format specifier to get the input integers.

If you want to skip any characters that are before the first space then you can do this

```
scanf("%*[^ \n] %d %d", &first, &last);
```

This is exactly the same as the earlier one only difference is here no limit of 32 characters like before.

In all these cases necessarily check the return value of `scanf` - that level of error checking is needed.

The best is to use the `fgets` to get a finer control over the input. Take the whole line and then parse it using `strtol` etc.

I will add the comment as it is (Jonathan Leffler):

Note that `%*4s` will skip zero or more white space characters, then read up to `4` non-white-space characters, and stop at the next white space or when `4` characters have been read. The following blank skips zero or more white space. The `%d` also skips zero or more white space characters and then reads an integer (or fails). (Repeat for the second blank and `%d`.) If you want to skip `4` characters unconditionally, use `%*4c`, possibly with a blank before the `%` since`%c` does not skip white space. (`" %*4c"`).

Another choice mentioned by David C. Rankin is using the scanset where the digits are mentioned to be ignored. `scanf("%*[^0-9]%d %d",&first,&last)` will skip all the characters until a digit is found.